# How to get Form submit value in react-redux with rails backend?

Tags: javascript, forms, react-redux, action, dispatch

I have a Rails backend, with a list of ingredients. I am trying to use a Search Bar (form) to input an ingredient ID to find the appropriate ingredient.
    When I click the submit button of the form, I want the dispatch function getIngredient, with ID as argument, but with the approaches I have tried, I am not getting what is supposed to be the ID; it is undefined, or simply "an event". I only saw the error message briefly, so I don't have more details then that. It simply refreshes state, erasing the error messages.

I have tried having the value of the form `onSubmit={() => getIngredient(id)}`, it then returns as an event object. with `onSubmit={() => this.props.getIngredient(id)}` it returns undefined. Stating it simply as `onSubmit={getIngredient(id)}` also didn't work.

I have console.logged everything, and I found that it errors when it hits the dispatch action in `getIngredient(id)`, because the id is undefined.

The getIngredients method I have works, it was when trying to only grab one ingredient I have had trouble. I have read everything I could find about redux, react-redux, and even reselect to try and target the issue, and I have hit this wall.

IngredientForm.js component:

```
        <form onSubmit={(id) => getIngredient(id)}>
          <label value="Find Ingredient">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search By Id" />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Find Ingredient" />
        </form>

const mapDispatchToProps = { getIngredient }

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  const id = props.id;
  return {
    ingredients: state.ingredients.filter(ingredient => ingredient.id === id)
  };
};
```

Dispatch action creator in actions.js:

```
export function getIngredient(id) {
  return dispatch => {
        console.log("trying to get id to show up =>", id)
    dispatch(getIngredientRequest(id));
    return fetch(`v1/ingredients`)
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(getIngredientSuccess(json)))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

action:

```
export function getIngredientRequest(id) {
  return { type: GET_INGREDIENT_REQUEST, id };
}
```

reducer.js

```
function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log(action.type);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_INGREDIENTS_SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, ingredients: action.json.ingredients }
    case "GET_INGREDIENTS_REQUEST":
      console.log('Ingredients request received')
      return
    case "HIDE_INGREDIENTS":
      console.log('Ingredients are being hidden')
      return { ...state, ingredients: [] }
    case "GET_INGREDIENT_REQUEST":
      console.log('One Ingredient request received:', "id:", action.id)
      return
    case "GET_INGREDIENT_SUCCESS":
    console.log('GET_INGREDIENT_SUCCESS')
      return {
                ...state,
                ingredients: action.json.ingredients.filter(i => i.id)
            }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Server terminal window output:

````
Processing by StaticController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"page"=>"ingredients"}
  Rendering static/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered static/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 7.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because in [React Synthetic Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) - like `onSubmit` - the first parameter in the callback is always the `Event` object.
I recommend you to use controlled inputs. That means you keep the id value in the component's state and assign that value to the input. Whenever the user types a new id, you update the state and assign the new value to the input.

```
class Form extends React.Component {
 state = {
  id: ""
 };

 handleInputChange = event => {
  this.setState({ id: event.target.value });
 };

 render() {
  return (
   <form
    onSubmit={(event) => {
     event.preventDefault();
     getIngredient(this.state.id);
    }}
   >
    <label value="Find Ingredient">
     <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search By Id"
      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
      value={this.state.id}
     />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Find Ingredient" />
   </form>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Hey Mostafa! 
I am using redux so it is handling the state. Even so, I tried out your code: however it is throwing me a ```Uncaught ReferenceError: handleInputChange is not defined```. I tried making it a function and a const, but the same error persists.

Comment: @DavidBell sorry that was a mistake from me it should be this.handleInputChange 
I edited the code and by the way, because you are using redux doesn't mean you shouldn't use React state you can combine them together like make React state for simple UI state and redux for the whole application data

Comment: So it's not giving me any errors, it simply refreshes. I have dev tools installed, and I can see the onChange change the state as I type into the field, however pressing the button simply updates the field and erases everything with no trace in the dev tools. I can see the getIngredient function as a prop: 
```{
  "ingredients": [],
  "getIngredient": "fn()"
}```
Tomorrow I will seperate the formReducer, and use combineReducers to make everything more standard, and I'll report back!

Comment: @DavidBell I know what causes this it is because of the default behavior of the submit event will edit the code again and prevent this default behavior from happening

Comment: The ID is being correctly communicated to the getIngredient method now, thank you. The Redux/React relationship has confused me. I wish my getIngredient method worked but that is another issue.